# Help Installing propietary AMD Drivers on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, fglrx, gpu

I know that this question has been posted already (kind of) but those seems not to apply to my case, as with the tutorials I found online, seems to be different.

So I have a samsung laptop (AMD APU A6-1450 with integrated grapichs) i was trying to play some games, then i realised that CSGO for example runs at 15/20 FPS, which make me wonder, so i check and seems I'm using the ubuntu open source drivers.

I went to AMD website and download my drivers from their website, which for my current APU and GPU its "Crimson Edition 15.12 Proprietary Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64" so I downloaded and here is the first problem, I realize its a .deb package, not a tar.gz with a .sh file inside to run (which shows up in all the tutorials online to install propietary drivers), i check just in case the .pdf in AMD website which said would help to install the drivers, but that pdf is beyond complicated and misleading, (and also refers to a .tar.gz file with a run file inside, not a deb package). Anyway i thought it would be easier since its a deb, so i tried to install it by dpkg -i amdblablabla.deb fail becasue fglrx-core dependence not installed and other "libtq4" (something like this i forgot the name) also "missing dependecies or not installed".

So i tried, sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get check and sudo apt-get -f install

but it didnt help (dependecies didnt installed) it just suggets me to delete the fglrx deb I installed previously

I tried the following (according to AMD pdf file if missing dependencies) sudo apt-get build-dep fglrx-core and apt-get build-dep "libtq4" which are the dependencies missing, but fail because it didn't recognice the packages or doesn't found those packages.

So here is where I stop because I fail to find a tutorial for a .deb package to install AMD propietary drivers, I'm missing something here? or what I'm doing wrong, i ask becasue i'm not that knwoledged of ubuntu, i read somewhere that first you have to uninstall the open source drivers or purge it, but not Im not 100% sure if i have to do that for my case, since my ubuntu is very clean install...

Anyway thank you in advance. :)

Comment: To install a .deb package, you'd cd to where it is, for example, `cd Downloads`, and run `sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb`. However, the package is for 14.04, and you are on 18.04, so I am not sure it is the right one.

Comment: Hi @mikewhatever I don't know if you read all, but of course that's the first thing I tried, and as I wrote it didn't work, because dependencies, apt-get -f install didn't work as neither apt-get build-up "dependencies packagename" As for the tutorial I found online to install AMD drivers on Ubuntu 18.04, because they follow different phat since the driver they got from AMD is a tar.gz with a script for run, not a .deb package like my case.

Comment: that drivers you want to isntall use fglrx, but that driver support has been gone long time ago, I think that's the reason you cannot find the fglrx-core dependencies online, so you would have to use Ubuntu 14.04 to use that propietary drivers. Or just simply use the Mesa Drivers that you already have installed in ubuntu (be sure you're using your dedicated GPU isntead or integrated).

Comment: I am afraid there is no proprietary driver by AMD for your hardware. In other words, radeon hd 8250 is not supported by anything other then the radeon driver. That is the important part you've missed.

Answer (score -1):

I recently had the same problem. The answer is here (in Russian):

https://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=311456.msg2424144#msg2424144

And the link with translation (ru->eng):

https://translate.google.fi/translate?hl=en&tab=TT&sl=ru&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fforum.ubuntu.ru%2Findex.php%3Ftopic%3D311456.msg2424144%23msg2424144

Shortly speaking, the user with the name Metal Militia is right. The latest LTS Ubuntu where you could use AMD Radeon HD 4000 series - Radeon HD 8000 series cards was Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, so there is no proprietary driver by AMD for your hardware